How to erode cloud edges on x,y directions to sharpen edges
I have a noisy pointcloud of a flat surface that I want to estimate its dimensions, so I want to sharpen the edges, to do so I decided to use a statistical approach using mean of histogram to filter points on the edges as follows:

import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def filter_cloud_borders(pcl:o3d.geometry.PointCloud, visu:bool=True) -> o3d.geometry.PointCloud:
    #
    min_bbox = pcl.get_minimal_oriented_bounding_box()
    # Box Pose
    box_pose = np.eye(4)
    box_pose[:3, :3] = min_bbox.R
    box_pose[:3, 3] = min_bbox.center
    # align it to center
    pcl.transform(np.linalg.inv(box_pose))
    pcl_pts = np.asarray(pcl.points)

    # compute the histogram of X and Y values separately
    hist_x, bins_x = np.histogram(pcl_pts[:, 0], bins=500)
    hist_y, bins_y = np.histogram(pcl_pts[:, 1], bins=500)

    # compute the mean of the histogram values for X and Y separately
    mean_hist_x = np.mean(hist_x)
    mean_hist_y = np.mean(hist_y)

    # find indices where histogram values are greater than the mean for X and Y
    ## TODO: adjust these limits properly to avoid over cropping
    crop_factor = 0.9
    indices_greater_than_mean_x = np.where(hist_x > crop_factor*mean_hist_x)[0]
    indices_greater_than_mean_y = np.where(hist_y > crop_factor*mean_hist_y)[0]

    # Filter point cloud points based on X and Y values
    filtered_points = pcl_pts[
        (pcl_pts[:, 0] > bins_x[indices_greater_than_mean_x[0]]) & 
        (pcl_pts[:, 0] < bins_x[indices_greater_than_mean_x[-1]]) &
        (pcl_pts[:, 1] > bins_y[indices_greater_than_mean_y[0]]) &
        (pcl_pts[:, 1] < bins_y[indices_greater_than_mean_y[-1]])
    ]

    # apply transformation to the filtered points
    transformed_points = np.hstack((filtered_points, np.ones((len(filtered_points), 1))))  # Convert points to homogeneous coordinates
    transformed_points = np.dot(box_pose, transformed_points.T).T[:, :3]  # Apply transformation

    new_cloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    new_cloud.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(transformed_points)
    new_cloud.estimate_normals()
    #
    # pcl.transform(box_pose)
    #
    if(visu):
        plt.plot(hist_x)
        plt.axhline(y=mean_hist_x, color="g", linestyle="-")
        plt.axvline(x=indices_greater_than_mean_x[0], color="m", linestyle="-")
        plt.axvline(x=indices_greater_than_mean_x[-1], color="r", linestyle="-")
        plt.show()

        plt.plot(hist_y)
        plt.axhline(y=mean_hist_y, color="g", linestyle="-")
        plt.axvline(x=indices_greater_than_mean_y[0], color="m", linestyle="-")
        plt.axvline(x=indices_greater_than_mean_y[-1], color="r", linestyle="-")
        plt.show()
        # Origin
        origin = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(
            size=0.1, origin=[0, 0, 0])
        # colors
        min_bbox.color = [0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
        new_cloud.paint_uniform_color([0.5, 0.3, 0.7])
        ## Visualization
        o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([origin, pcl, new_cloud, min_bbox])
    
    return new_cloud


This approach doesn't behave the same always as for different runs I get different histogram distributions using same pointcloud! this might be caused by the minimal bounding box is not the same (especially orientation) for each run! but not sure.
Can you please tell me how can I solve that please?


The solution is to get the rotation of the box from the points rather than the rotation which might be random:
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

def pose_from_obbox(obbox:o3d.geometry.OrientedBoundingBox) -> np,ndarray:
    vertices = np.asarray(obbox.get_box_points())
    """
    Reference: https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/cpp_api/classopen3d_1_1geometry_1_1_oriented_bounding_box.html#a8e63a202d0b2bf72014e12c42dd9908b
    ///      ------- x
    ///     /|
    ///    / |
    ///   /  | z
    ///  y
    ///      0 ------------------- 1
    ///       /|                /|
    ///      / |               / |
    ///     /  |              /  |
    ///    /   |             /   |
    /// 2 ------------------- 7  |
    ///   |    |____________|____| 6
    ///   |   /3            |   /
    ///   |  /              |  /
    ///   | /               | /
    ///   |/                |/
    /// 5 ------------------- 4
    """
    # # Define edges of the cube
    edges = [
        (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)
    ]
    # Calculate edge lengths
    edge_lengths = np.linalg.norm(vertices[np.array(edges)[:, 0]] - vertices[np.array(edges)[:, 1]], axis=1)

    # Find longest and shortest edges
    longest_edge_idx = np.argmax(edge_lengths)
    shortest_edge_idx = np.argmin(edge_lengths)

    # Define x-axis direction vector
    x_axis = vertices[edges[longest_edge_idx][1]] - vertices[edges[longest_edge_idx][0]]
    x_axis = x_axis / np.linalg.norm(x_axis)

    # Define z-axis direction vector
    z_axis = vertices[edges[shortest_edge_idx][1]] - vertices[edges[shortest_edge_idx][0]]
    z_axis = z_axis / np.linalg.norm(z_axis)

    # Calculate y-axis direction vector
    y_axis = np.cross(z_axis, x_axis)
    y_axis = y_axis / np.linalg.norm(y_axis)

    # Build transformation matrix
    center = np.mean(vertices, axis=0)
    
    pose = np.eye(4)
    pose[:3, 3] = center
    pose[:3, 0] = x_axis
    #
    if z_axis[2]<0:
        pose[:3, 1] = - y_axis
        pose[:3, 2] = - z_axis
    else:
        pose[:3, 1] = y_axis
        pose[:3, 2] = z_axis        
    return pose

